# Receiving an error pushing from RStudio to GitHub

Tags: git, github, rstudio, push

I am trying to push from RStudio to GitHub for the first time. I received this error message:

error: cannot run rpostback-askpass: No such file or directory
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured

I originally thought I had the url wrong for the Git repository, so I created a new one and tried again. I received the same error message.

I read one suggestion that said to use the following code to correct this:

```
git remote rm origin
```

I entered this in Terminal and received the following error message:

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I would really appreciate any suggestions for how to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the

> fatal: not a git repository

error make sure you are in your git repository directory when you issue the command to rm the remote.

If you are not familiar with terminal you can use something like:
`cd ~/Desktop/myGitRepoDir` to get there once you open terminal.

Also using `pwd` in terminal will tell your current working directory.